# What does the Unorderable Type error mean in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
page1 = urlopen("http://www.beans-r-us.biz/prices.html")
page2 = urlopen("http://www.beans-r-us.biz/prices-loyalty.html")
text1 = page1.read().decode("utf8")
text2 = page2.read().decode("utf8")
where = text2.find(">$")
start_of_price = where + 2
end_of_price = where + 6
price_loyal = text2[start_of_price:end_of_price]
price = text1[234:238]
password = 5501
p = input("Loyalty Customers Password? : ")
passkey = int(p)

if passkey == password:
    while price_loyal > 4.74:
        if price_loyal < 4.74:
            print("Here is the loyal customers price :) :")
            print(price_loyal)
        else:
            print( "Price is too high to make a profit, come back later :) ")
else:
    print("Sorry incorrect password :(, here is the normal price :")
    print(price)
input("Thanks for using our humble service, come again :), press enter to close this window.")
```

The problem I'm having is that it runs until I get the the 4.74 part. Then it stops and complains about an unorderable type. I'm completely confused as to what that means.

Comment: Isn't `price_loyal` a string (even if it contains numbers that you have found with `find`) that you are then trying to compare to a numeric value (4.75)? What happens if you try `float(price_royal)`

Comment: Unlike other popular scripting languages, python is strictly typed.  This means that if you want to convert a string to a number, you have to do so explicitly.

Comment: isn't that an infinite loop?  You never manipulate price_loyal inside

Comment: @StevenBurnap Only on Python 3 (which is what he's using)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`price_loyal` is a string (even if it contains numbers that you have found with `find`) that you are trying to compare to a numeric value (4.75)? For your comparison try

`float(price_loyal)`

**UPDATE** (thanks @agf):

With Python ***v 3.x*** you get the error message you mentioned.

```
>>> price_loyal = '555.5'
>>> price_loyal  > 5000.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    price_loyal > 5000.0
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > float()
>>>
```

whereas

```
>>> float(price_loyal) > 5000.0
False
```

The version of Python makes a difference in this case, so probably a good idea to always mention what version one is working with. *Previously ... with Python **v 2.x***

Your comparisons will be off without converting your `string` to a `float` first. E.g.,

```
price_loyal
'555.5'
```

This comparison with string and float gives `True`

```
price_loyal > 5000.0
True
```

This comparison with float and float gives `False` as it should

```
float(price_loyal) > 5000.0
False
```

There might be other problems, but this looks like one.

Comment: That's the behavior on Python 2. The behavior he's getting is on Python 3.

Comment: thanks, had to convert both  4.75 and python_loyal into floats using the float(), solved >.>

Comment: @Humility It shouldn't be necessary to convert 7.75 to a `float` since it already is one, just the string `price_loyal`

Answer (score 2):

I'm no Python coder, but it looks like it's complaining about you trying to compare a string to a float and I guess Python doesn't juggle for you.

You should convert the string to a float, however that's done in Python.

Comment: `foo_float = float(foo_string)`

Comment: thank you,all the float didnt fix it however  as Mr. Burnap said explicit and KDi as well so im just going to take it outside the infinite loop