# Unable to solve TypeError: unorderable types: time.struct_time() > float()

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, scheduler

I want a function to run at specific date and time. I am using scheduler.enterabs(). It is giving me following error:

```
START: 1561263892.1316419
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "timer.py", line 78, in <module>
    scheduler.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sched.py", line 137, in run
    if time > now:
TypeError: unorderable types: time.struct_time() > float()
```

```
import sched,time
scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
def print_event():
    print('inside print_event')
    print ('EVENT:', time.time())

print ('START:', time.time())
scheduler.enterabs(time.strptime("2019-06-23 09:55:00", "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S"),1,print_event)

scheduler.run()
```

I want to run print_event() on specific date and time. Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `timefunc` given to `sched.scheduler` is `time.time` which works with simple float numbers as time only.

This means the time given to `scheduler.enterabs` must be a float, too. `strptime` returns a `struct_time` tuple instead.

Solution: Use `time.mktime` to convert the tuple to a float time.

Answer (score 0):

For,    `scheduler.enterabs(time, priority, action, argument=(), kwargs={})`

The time argument should be a numeric type compatible with the return value of the timefunc function passed to the constructor.

So, the return value of time.strptime is struct_time as returned by gmtime() or localtime() which is not comparable with float value returned by time.time.

Check this answer for better explanation:

[What does the Unorderable Type error mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779187/what-does-the-unorderable-type-error-mean-in-python)