# Python add new column values based on multiple conditions in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two data frames,

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col_A':['AA','AA','AB','AB','AA','AA','AB','AB'],  
                   'col_B':['BB','BB','BB','BB','BC','BC','BC','BC'],  
                   'col_HIGH':[10,20,10,20,10,20,10,20],  
                   'col_LOW':[0,10.0001,0,10.0001,0,10.0001,0,10.0001],  
                   'col_D':[6,16,7,17,8,18,9,19]})
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['01','11','21','02','12','22','03','13','23','04','14','24','05','15','25','06','16','26','07','17','27','08','18','28'],  
'col_A':['AA','AA','AA','AA','AA','AA','AB','AB','AB','AB','AB','AB','AA','AA','AA','AA','AA','AA','AB','AB','AB','AB','AB','AB'],  
'col_B':['BB','BB','BB','BB','BB','BB','BB','BB','BB','BB','BB','BB','BC','BC','BC','BC','BC','BC','BC','BC','BC','BC','BC','BC',],  
'col_C':[5,7,9,15,17,19,5,7,9,15,17,19,5,7,9,15,17,19,5,7,9,15,17,19]})
```

I want to create col_D in df2 and use values of col_D in df1 to fill in based on multiple conditions including col_A and col_B match from df1 and df2, col_C value in df2 is in the range of col_HIGH and col_LOW in df1. What is the fastest way?

Comment: can you add example of expected output?

Comment: Hi Franky, Your question does not speficy what is the output you are looking for. Kindly revise and update.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. My expected output is as Scott Boston provided. Based on the values in col_A, col_B and col_C in df1, mapping the row in df2 and add the value in col_D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way using `join` with `pd.IntervalIndex`:

```
# Create a new dataframe with MultiIndex of col_A, col_B, and pd.IntervalIndex defined by
# LOW and HIGH columns
df1i = df1.set_index(['col_A', 'col_B', pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df1['col_LOW'], df1['col_HIGH'], name='col_C')])

# Use join
df_out = df2.set_index(['col_A', 'col_B', 'col_C']).join(df1i).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   col_A col_B  col_C  ID  col_HIGH  col_LOW  col_D
0     AA    BB      5  01        10   0.0000      6
1     AA    BB      7  11        10   0.0000      6
2     AA    BB      9  21        10   0.0000      6
3     AA    BB     15  02        20  10.0001     16
4     AA    BB     17  12        20  10.0001     16
5     AA    BB     19  22        20  10.0001     16
6     AB    BB      5  03        10   0.0000      7
7     AB    BB      7  13        10   0.0000      7
8     AB    BB      9  23        10   0.0000      7
9     AB    BB     15  04        20  10.0001     17
10    AB    BB     17  14        20  10.0001     17
11    AB    BB     19  24        20  10.0001     17
12    AA    BC      5  05        10   0.0000      8
13    AA    BC      7  15        10   0.0000      8
14    AA    BC      9  25        10   0.0000      8
15    AA    BC     15  06        20  10.0001     18
16    AA    BC     17  16        20  10.0001     18
17    AA    BC     19  26        20  10.0001     18
18    AB    BC      5  07        10   0.0000      9
19    AB    BC      7  17        10   0.0000      9
20    AB    BC      9  27        10   0.0000      9
21    AB    BC     15  08        20  10.0001     19
22    AB    BC     17  18        20  10.0001     19
23    AB    BC     19  28        20  10.0001     19
```

Output:

Comment: Your code works fine on my small example. However, when I use it to the real large dataframes, I get the error "unorderable types: Interval() > float()" on df_out. Any ideas?

Comment: Be sure that your columns are dtype float or int and not object/string.  In your larger dataframe, what are the dtypes of High and Low columns?

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10779212/6361531 You might trying to created a interval with strings instead of numbers.

Comment: They are all float64. It seems that the error is about comparing interval with float. If the interval is created with strings, is there anyway to compare it with col_C in df2?

Comment: Yes.  then can you cast your col_c in Df2 to a number first before join?

Comment: I'm confused. In this small example, the code works with the dtype of col_C is int64, col_HIGH is int64 and col_LOW is float64. After casting my large data into same format, I still get the error interval() > int().

Comment: When I change my example to all float64, the code still works. However, it does not work on my large data with all float64. This makes me start thinking maybe something else about TypeError: unorderable types: Interval() > float().

Comment: Maybe memory.  Try cutting your data in half running each half does both run?  Maybe it is some bad data somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to provide which condition you want to use.

1. If it's a kind of mapping you want use a dictionary

```py
dictionary = {'AA': 100, 'BB': 200, 'BC': 300}
df['new_column'] = df['old_column'].map(dictionary)
```

*Note* : You can also use `.apply()` above

2. You can also use `if/else` conditions

```py
  df['new_column'] = ['value1' if x==100 else 'value2' for x in df['old column']]
```